# QPushButton css pressed

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

I need to change the background image of a `QPushButton` when its state is pressed. I tried with this css:

```
QPushButton { background: transparent; border: none;} 
QPushButton:pressed { image: url(\mypath\settings_press.png); }
```

but a runtime I got the following error:

> Could not parse stylesheet of widget

Any idea?

Comment: I'm not positive on this, but you may want to try forward slashes instead of backslashes

Comment: What does " I'm not positive on this " mean?

Comment: @Chris thanks, seems that the issue is related to the slahes direction

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of the examples of Qt stylesheets I've seen use UNIX style paths, so your CSS should look like:

```
QPushButton { background: transparent; border: none;} 
QPushButton:pressed { image: url(/mypath/settings_press.png); }
```

Also, URLs for Qt stylesheets need to be a relative path to a Qt resource  like:

```
QPushButton:pressed { image: url(':images/settings_press.png') }
```

or absolute paths like:

```
QPushButton:pressed { image: url('/usr/share/icons/crystalsvg/settings_press.png') }
```

I would go the resource route unless you can absolutely guarantee the install path of your image.

Comment: ok, but I am on  a Windows CE device. Does it need the  forward slashes?

Comment: Yes. Qt should take care of doing the translation for you since you're on a Windows CE device.

Comment: it's probably due to how the path is specified. I've updated the answer to include what I know regarding pathing in Qt stylesheets.

Comment: I think the accessor needs to be "background-color" not just "background."

Comment: blackbelt, what was the geometry issue? I have the same problem, stylesheet sets fine, but icon doesn't show.